# Curves lying above or below the x-axis.

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

The curve $y = (k+1)x^2 - 3x + (k+1)$ lies below the x-axis. Find a set of values for $k$.
So, I know this means there are no real solutions for $y = 0$, hence we use the $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ method. However, why is the answer just $k<-5/2$ and not $k<-5/2$ OR $k>1/2$?

Comment: The case $k> \frac{1}{2}$ corresponds to the curve being entirely above the $x-$axis.

Comment: In a quadratic equation two roots appear. One should be discarded depending on the problem; $ k>\frac12$ is the opposite situation of what is wanted ( all of the parabola lies above $x-$ axis),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if the discriminant is negative it just means no real solutions. It does not guarantee that the function is all negative or all positive, just that it does not change sign. So you need to plug in some number, and see the value of $y$. The trivial one is $x=0$.

Comment: So what if k ends up lying BETWEEN two values one of which is negative, say -1<k<5?

Comment: You need to look at the discriminant. Your $k$ is either less than $-5/2$ OR greater than $1/2$. You cannot have $k$ in the interval $[-5/2,1/2]$, otherwise you have real solutions.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

it must be $k+1<0$ and
$$(k+1)\frac{9}{4(k+1)^2}-\frac{9}{2(k+1)}+k+1<0$$
can you solve this?